# Windows form throws Argument exception when the control size is larger in design mode

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a third party control on windows forms and the third party control(Control size (829px,1169px)) is rendered based on Measurement unit pixel. I have changed its measurement unit to centimeter in order to render the control in centimeter. After changing the measurement unit i have moved the control through mouse to place it in desired location while moving the control the "Argument Exception was unhandled" exception is thrown by the Method Bitmap(width= 34000cm,height = 45000cm). This exception is thrown only when the form has default size.
I have changed the size of the form to maximum size and again i move the control, now the control is moved without any exceptions but little bit slower. I don't know why this exception is raised when the form is in default size?

Is the .net renders the control based on the form size ?

whether this is issue in net or not?
Note: Control runs perfect during runtime while changing Measurement unit.....

Can any one help me on this?????

I have posted my stack strace with this question.

Thanks in advance..............

[image]
Stack strace:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
```

Message="Parameter is not valid."
  Source="System.Drawing"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat format)
       at Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Diagram.LayoutGrid.Draw(Graphics grfx, RectangleF rectGrid) in C:\Users\amsathm\Desktop\Source\Trunk\Base\Entities\LayoutGrid.cs:line 495
       at Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Diagram.View.Draw(Graphics grfx, RectangleF rectClip) in C:\Users\amsathm\Desktop\Source\Trunk\Base\MVC\View.cs:line 1891
       at Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Diagram.Controls.Diagram.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) in C:\Users\amsathm\Desktop\Source\Trunk\Windows\Controls\Diagram.cs:line 4152
       at Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.ScrollControl.OnEnsurePaintCodeJitted()
       at Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.ScrollControl.EnsurePaintCodeJitted(Boolean ignoreVisible)
       at Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.ScrollControl.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.ScrollControl.WndProc(Message& msg)
       at Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Diagram.Controls.Diagram.WndProc(Message& m) in C:\Users\amsathm\Desktop\Source\Trunk\Windows\Controls\Diagram.cs:line 4836
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

`Bitmap` constructor could throw `ArgumentException` when `PixelFormat` value is specified whose name does not start with Format. Please verify what value is being passed, use the format that starts with [Formatxxx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx).

Comment: But it moves without exceptions when form size is maximum.

Comment: I have got this exception only when moving the control in design mode. In run time it works perfectly...